# how to put dropdown result in textbox field in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

hi guys can anyone help me i have reach to my problem but i can't pass the value from div to input field which need please 
   page1.php

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error);
$db   = mysql_select_db('employee', $conn) or die (mysql_error);
$select = "SELECT * FROM employee ";
$result = mysql_query($select);
$option = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
$option .= '<option       value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['employee_name'].'</option>';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Retrieve data from database using Ajax</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getData(q, a){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'loademployeedata.php?empid='+q, //call storeemdata.php to store form data
                success: function(html) {
                    var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById(a);
                    ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = html;
                }
            });
        }
         $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tyt").live("change", function() {
        $("#ab  ").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));

    });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <select id="tyt" onchange="getData(this.value, 'dis')" >
          <?php
            echo $option;
          ?>
        </select>
        <div id="dis" >
        </div><input name="" type="text"  id="ab" >
    </form>
</body>
```

second connecting page is

```
<?php
$empid = $_GET['empid'];
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing    Connection with Server..
$db = mysql_select_db("employee", $connection); // Selecting Database
if (isset($empid)) {
$query = " SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = '$empid'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $a=$row['employee_salary'];?>
    <?php echo $a; ?>
 <?php }

  }
  mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed
  ?>
```

i just need to put the value instead of div means into input field

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested):

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die (mysql_error);
    $db   = mysql_select_db('employee', $conn) or die (mysql_error);
    $select = "SELECT * FROM employee ";
    $result = mysql_query($select);
    $option = '';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
        $option .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['employee_name'].'</option>';
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Retrieve data from database using Ajax</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on("change", "#tyt", function() {
                var tmp = $(this).val();
                $("#ab").val(tmp);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'loademployeedata.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: 'empid='+q, //call storeemdata.php to store form data
                    success: function(recd) {
                        $('#a').val(recd);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <select id="tyt" onchange="getData(this.value, 'dis')" >
          <?php echo $option; ?>
        </select>
        <div id="dis"></div>
        <input id="ab" type="text">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: sir its giving me id number value in input field but i only want to print salary  in input field